# Image stored in mysql BLOB type through PHP, need some help for displaying the images

Tags: php, mysql, blob

php

```
include("connect_to_database.php");

if( !isset($_FILES["image"]) ){

echo "upload the file";

}else{
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id=1");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image["image"]; 
echo $image;
}
```

html

```
<form action="newindex.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" >
</form>
```

Above code displaying the corresponding id's image which is already uploaded in mysql in BLOB format.

Now, I need to display images of last 6 id's or all the images in database. I have tried the below code but its not working instead it's displaying 1 image.

php

```
include("connect_to_database.php");<br>

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY id DESC");

while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
$image = $rows["image"]; 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Well, you obviously cannot concatenate all your images into one single file.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't output multiple images into same response. The web browser does not expect/understand another image after the first one, just as copying two jpg files into same file won't work on desktop.

Instead, create another (dynamic) page containing all the links to the images (`<img src="img.php?id=3">`). The web browser will then request the images one at a time.

```
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id=$id");
```

(Please note code similar to above is really insecure, one should never use input values directly in SQL queries in any public environment. I'd also recommend using PDO instead for executing the queries).

Comment: Nice answer (I like the desktop analogy). I think the note about insecure code no longer applies since you are casting ID to integer.

Comment: Thanks @Jari Karppanen:
As u said i started new php page image.php, instead of while loop i tried foreach in index.php as 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY id DESC");   


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);<br>

foreach ($row as $img) {
   echo '<img src="image.php?id='.$img["id"].'">';
}


In the new page image.php i have coded :

$query = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM upload WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];



But its resulting blank small images structures instead of images.

Comment: Since you already had a working code producing one image, I suggest you try manually to retrieve an image from the "slave page", and once you get proper output then try with the page requesting multiple images. Any warnings or text outputted (empty lines) from the slave page prior to the actual image data would prevent the image from being shown. Perhaps try ob_clean() just before outputting the image data.

Comment: Thanks! its all working with displaying multiple images stored in database.